# Modal dialog doesn't darken the background on android

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

I'm using Dialog in my Codename one application and it works fine on iOS and windows phone. On android it blocks the rest of the UI but it doesn't darken the rest of the UI like it does on iOS or WIN platform...

I'm using following code to display the dialog:

```
Dialog.show("Title", "Text", "OK", null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the parent form you can set the tint color or set the global tint color thru the theme constants (Constants tab in the theme within the designer). Or via the DefaultLookAndFeel which also allows to set it globally.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I used the tintColor constant. It's good to know that the value of the tintColor constant is in aarrggbb format.